# Help to parameterize curve for complex integration

Tags: complex-analysis

Can someone help me to parameterize  $\vert z-3i\vert+\vert z+3i\vert=20 $ where z is acomplex number.? I have tried breaking z into sine and cosine and simplifying it came to the conclusion of $sin\theta= 10{\sqrt10}i$. What will be the range of theta and is ther any other approach of doing the sum?

Comment: It may be useful to think geometrically about the initial equation. The LHS is the sum of the distances of a point $z$ from the points $\pm 3i$, so the solution set will consist of all $z$ for which the combined distance is 20. Do you recognize what geometric figure is defined in this fashion?

Comment: @Semiclassical Ellipse?

Comment: Yep. More precisely, it'll be an ellipse with major and minor axes being the imaginary and real axes respectively. If you then find the points which lie on these axes, you'll have enough info to write the ellipse in standard form. In that form, the parametrization is immediate. (This is the substance of Henning Markheim's answer, so I'll leave this as a comment.)

Answer (score 0):

The solution set of your equation is an ellipse with foci at $\pm 3i$, major axis $20$ and minor axis $2\sqrt{10^2-3^2}=2\sqrt{91}$ -- so
$$ t \mapsto \sqrt{91} \sin t + 10i\cos t$$
should do.

Answer (score 0):

let $$z=x+iy$$ then we have $$\sqrt{x^2+(y-3)^2}+\sqrt{x^2+(y+3)^2}=20$$